# Is there a way to solve this internal error in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just wrote a simple hello world program in Intellij and this is the output when I tried to run the program.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.IllegalAccessError) class com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil (in unnamed module @0x306279ee) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x306279ee
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the release JDK version, not ea and update to the latest IntelliJ IDEA version: jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html

Comment: For some reason, when I use the 1.8 version of the JDK, it works